# Does rsync handle multiple backups copies?

Tags: rsync

I've read this tutorial: http://www.marksanborn.net/howto/use-rsync-for-daily-weekly-and-full-monthly-backups/

But I was wondering, if I want a daily backup and weekly backup as they suggest, I do need twice the amount of space of my data on my backup server ?

So if my adata are 500MB, I need 1GB of space (500GB for daily backups, and 500 for weekly backups ?)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need twice the space. If that's not acceptable, then you'll have to look for a backup solution a little more sophisticated than rsync, that will do proper differential backups and only store data twice if it's actually been modified.

Answer (score 6):

> [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/): Using rsync and hard
>   links, it is possible to keep
>   multiple, full backups instantly
>   available. The disk space required is
>   just a little more than the space of
>   one full backup, plus incrementals.

I've got Rsnapshot's setup that will keep 6 copies/versions per day, 7 days a week, 4 a month and for as much as 6 months. While it will copy and store entire files, only a small portion of the total count of files would usually be changing on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your backups on a ZFS volume with deduplication turned on then you can just let the filesystem handle that issue for you with the bonus feature that you can also set ZFS to compress the files as well.

Comment: Deduplication should NOT be used too easily, it consumes far more resources than normal. Instead, using snapshots and overwriting files is the first thing to look at. Have a look at RSYNC's option `--inplace` and NOT use `--whole-file`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at BackupPC - it uses rsync as one of its backup tools but handles space very cleverly by hard linking between identical files in backup sets:

http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/

From the docs...

Features include:

- A clever pooling scheme minimizes disk storage and disk I/O. Identical files across multiple backups of the same or different PC are stored only once (using hard links), resulting in substantial savings in disk storage and disk writes.
- Optional compression provides additional reductions in storage (around 40%). The CPU impact of compression is low since only new files (those not already in the pool) need to be compressed.